# How to create a 3 way bi-directional relationship with @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

### My entities are set up as such:

### Client

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "client")
    public class Client {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        
        ...
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
        @JsonManagedReference
        private List<Project> projects;
    }
```

### Project

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "project")
    public class Project {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        
        ...
    
        @ManyToOne(name= "client")
        @JsonBackReference
        private Client client;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
        @JsonManagedReference
        private List<Listing> listings;
    }
```

### Listing

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "listing")
    public class Listing{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        
        ...

        @ManyToOne(name= "project")
        @JsonBackReference
        private Project project;
    }
```

Currently, If I make a call to a specific client by ID then I will get the Client, their projects, and the listings for that project. This works as it should. However, when I make a call to the Project by ID I only get the listings of that project, I would also like to know WHICH Client OWNS that project. Similarly, when I call Listing by ID then I ONLY receive the listing with that ID, I would also like the PROJECT which OWNS that Listing as well as the CLIENT which owns it, is this possible to do? Thank you.

Comment: There are many tutorials (see https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) on JsonBackReference which show it will be excluded from the JSON - so it will not behave the way you want. Including the client will serialize all its projects, so you might as well just fetch the client itself directly, as it will include this project within its projects.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

**@JsonManagedReference** is the forward part of reference – the one that gets serialized normally.
**@JsonBackReference** is the back part of reference – it will be omitted from serialization.
The serialized Item object does not contain a reference to the Client object.

Use **@JsonIdentityInfo**

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "id")
public class Client

@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "id")
public class Project

@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "id")
public class Listing
```

More info here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion